# Finding product in category

Tags: java, ebay-api

I need to find products in different categories on eBay. But when I use the tutorial code

```
ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.FindProductsRequestType request = new ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.FindProductsRequestType();
request.setCategoryID("Art");
request.setQueryKeywords("furniture");
```

I get the following error: `QueryKeywords, CategoryID and ProductID cannot be used together.`

So how is this done?

EDIT: the tutorial code is [here.](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1853)

EDIT2: the link to the tutorial code died, apparently. I've continued to search and the `category` cannot be used with the `keyword` search, but there's a `Domain` that you could presumably add to the request, but sadly it's not in the API - so I'm not sure if indeed it can be done.

The less-than-great eBay API doc is [here.](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html)

This is my full request:

```
Shopping service = new ebay.apis.eblbasecomponents.Shopping();
ShoppingInterface port = service.getShopping();

bp = (BindingProvider) port;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);
 // Add the logging handler
List<Handler> handlerList = bp.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
if (handlerList == null) {
    handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
}
LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler();
handlerList.add(loggingHandler);
bp.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerList);

Map<String,Object> requestProperties = bp.getRequestContext();
Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
requestProperties.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);
httpHeaders.put("X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", Collections.singletonList(CALLNAME));
httpHeaders.put("X-EBAY-API-APP-ID", Collections.singletonList(APPID));
httpHeaders.put("X-EBAY-API-VERSION", Collections.singletonList(VERSION));
requestProperties.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);

// initialize WS operation arguments here
FindProductsRequestType request = new FindProductsRequestType();
request.setAvailableItemsOnly(true);
request.setHideDuplicateItems(true);
request.setMaxEntries(2);
request.setPageNumber(1);
request.setQueryKeywords("Postcard");
request.setDomain("");
```

The last line, which should set the domain like I need to, does not compile. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT 3: I gave up on the Java API and I'm doing direct REST. The categories on eBay are actually domains now, and the URL looks like this:

```
String findProducts = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=" + APPID 
            + "&siteid=0&version=525&"
            + "&AvailableItemsOnly=true"
            + "&QueryKeywords=" + keywords
            + "&MaxEntries=10"
            + "&DomainName=" + domainName;
```

This works, but you want to hear a joke? It seems like not all the domains are listed [here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/ProductDomains.html#US) and so it doesn't really solve this problem. Pretty disappointing work by eBay.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tutorial code?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ChetanKinger The link is dead.

Comment: @Mureinik I believe the comment was intended for @Eddy?

Comment: @ChetanKinger indeed. Sorry for the noise. Mea culpa.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I edited the question to add more info. The link, sadly, has apparently died.

Comment: If you guys care about this topic, I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for finding items based on keywords, in a category, is to use `findItemsAdvanced`. Could have saved me a lot of time if the docs for `FindProducts` stated this, instead of just saying that you can use either keyword search OR category search.

This is the `API URL`:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shoppingcallname=findItemsAdvanced&responseencoding=XML&appid=" + APPID 
+ "&siteid=0&version=525&"
+ "&AvailableItemsOnly=true"
+ "&QueryKeywords=" + keywords
+ "&categoryId=" + categoryId                               
+ "&MaxEntries=50
```

For completion, if you want to get a list of all the top categories you can use this:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=" + APPID + "&siteid=0&CategoryID=-1&version=729&IncludeSelector=ChildCategories
```